# Alfresco Listeners

Tags: java, alfresco, activiti

I'm trying to make a custom logic on start, end events of workflows in a programmatic way. I tried activiti executionListeners, but the problem was that I have to define a custom process and add the executionListener. and this works good.
but what I am asking is how can I do this without having to write a custom process, to the predefined workflows for example.

Comment: You need to override existing workflow.

Comment: You mean, I have to write the executionListeners, then add them to the process definition of the existing workflow ?

Comment: Yes.you need to do that.